# c++11 is it safe to return an initializer_list value?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, initializer-list, temp

I've this simple function:

```
initializer_list<int> f(){return {1,2,3};}
```

g++ gives a warning saying:

```
warning: returning temporary initializer_list does not extend the lifetime of the underlying array [-Winit-list-lifetime]
```

Is there any risk to return an `{1, 2, 3}`?
Thanks for explanations!

Comment: I suggest to return a `std::vector<int>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `initializer_list` behaves like a reference extending lifetime of a temporary (the temporary being the array).

Lifetime extension doesn't apply when returning references, so it doesn't apply here too. The compiler is right, the returned list is always dangling.